# Excel VBA array of strings to Outlook email "To" field

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I am trying to create a macro that will take a column of email addresses from my Excel sheet and populate the "To" field in an Outlook email.  I have the basics working, and I am able to create a new Outlook email message with the various field values I have specified - however, I cannot figure out how to populate multiple email addresses into the "To" field, for a single email.

As of right now, I am able to create an array with all of the desired email addresses, but can't figure out how to populate the array values into the Outlook "To" field.

Comment: show your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on Eugene's answer, edited to include the excel implementation

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss(addRng as Excel.Range)  
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
  Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  For Each cell in addRng
     Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add(cell.Value)
  Next cell  
  myItem.Subject = "Status Report"  
  myItem.Display  
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added Microsoft Outlook 15 reference, then also I am getting error "Object doesn't support type or method" in line no 3 (CreateItem).

Answer (score 1):

This might help but the concept is bit different as to the items. Hope this helps out- have used in the past for similar case but ofcourse, will only provide maproad.

```
Sub CreateMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngCc As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("B1")
    Set rngCc = .Range("B2")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("B3")
    Set rngBody = .Range(.Range("B4"), .Range("B4").End(xlDown))
End With
rngBody.Copy

With objMail
    .To = rngTo.Value
    .Cc = rngCc.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .Display
End With
SendKeys "^({v})", True

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngCc = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do with this "String Concentate" fuction I found here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx

But your solutions are much for straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865320(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class for adding multiple recipients. It also allows to specify the type of the Recipient: To, CC or BCC.

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss()  
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
  Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
  Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Dan Wilson")  
  myItem.Subject = "Status Report"  
  myItem.Display  
End Sub
```